# TypeError - Jest Configuration with Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am using jest for Angular 9 application

1. I install jest & jest-preset-angular
2. Created a setupJest.ts file in the root and import jest-preset-angular
3. add the Jest configuration in the package.json

```html
 "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
    ]
  }
```

4. modify the test script to use Jest instead of ng test.
5. run npm test

I got a TypeError

```html
TypeError: Jest: a transform must export something.
at Promise.all._config.transform.map (~\node_modules\@jest\transform\build\ScriptTransformer.js:386:19)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

My Jest file looks like this and it runs

```
{
"preset": "jest-preset-angular",
"setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!@ngrx|ngx-socket-io)" 
],
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "ts-jest"
},
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/dist/",
    "<rootDir>/src/test.ts"
],
"modulePaths": ["<rootDir>"]
```

}